# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n} $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question**

Does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n} $$ converge?

**Where I am at so far**

I feel like what I've written below isn't correct. Can you guys check out my solution please?

Let ($S_N$) be the sequence of partial sums for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n} $.

$S_{2n}$ = $-\sqrt{n}$ for all natural numbers.

$S_{2n-1}$ = $\sqrt{n}$ for all natural numbers.

($S_{2n}$) --> -∞ and ($S_{2n-1}$) --> ∞ as n --> ∞. Thus $S_N$ diverges.

I feel like what I've written above isn't correct. **Is it enough just to say $S_{2n}$ = $-\sqrt{n}$ for all natural numbers and ($S_{2n}$) --> -∞ thus ($S_N$) diverges.**

Comment: Bonus question: does $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{2N} (-1)^{n+1} \sqrt{n}$ converge ?

Comment: @PeterForeman He's only looking at the even partial sums.

Comment: @PeterForeman He's posting another question as a comment, which he shouldn't do, but if you read it again, you'll see that he's only considering the even-numbered partial sums, so the $n$th summand is $\sqrt{2N-1}-\sqrt{2N}$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the terms of the sequence do not tend to zero so the sum is divergent. There is no need to consider the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: So as my solution, would I write "The sequence ($S_N$) does not converge to $0$ thus by the null sequence test the series diverges"?

Comment: Not $S_n$ (the partial sums) but the terms of the sequence $a_n$. It is necessary that $(a_n)\to0$ for any sequence to converge.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not tend to zero, then the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$ does not converge.

Since the sequence $((-1)^{n+1} \sqrt{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not even converge, your series diverges.